# Text to Columns delimitter

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do Text to Columns with the `OtherChar` not just limited to one. Currently my code looks like this:

```
With Selection
    .TextToColumns Destination:=[A2], _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
        Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=True, _
        Space:=True, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="-", _
     TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End With
```

But I want the `OtherChar` to include these characters `"(, ), [, ], /, *"`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Replace other delimiters with "-" then convert to column.

Comment: I understand but it would require me to input the code all over again. I need to be in just one coding to have everything work. I tried adding multiple `OtherChar:=` on it but it's giving a compile error. I tried doing this as well `OtherChar:="-, (, ), [, ], /, *"` but it's only doing the first delimiter `"-"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty code.  Do not use * as delimiter as it will be treated as all in replace

```
Dim aDelim
Dim delim
Dim oRange As Range

aDelim = Split("(,),[,],/", ",")
Set oRange = Selection

For Each delim In aDelim
    oRange.Replace What:=delim, Replacement:="-"
    Debug.Print oRange.Text, delim
Next

oRange.TextToColumns Destination:=[A2], _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
    Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=True, _
    Space:=True, _
    Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:="-", _
 TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much! However, some of my content has `*` on it. How do I delimit that? Is there a way to do it?